# How did the elevator get to a planet?

Tags: physics, killjoys

Note: while I tried to keep the title more or less spoiler-free, this is about the most recent episodes of a show, so this question will definitely contain spoilers.

At the end of the third season of Killjoys, several main characters were in a space elevator (between two space stations) that was cut loose. At the beginning of the fourth season, we learn that the elevator crashed on an inhabited planet.

It is:

1. Unlikely that an elevator had either an FTL drive or (serious) maneuvering capabilities.
2. Improbable there are more inhabited planets in the quad. It's the quad, not the quint, we haven't heard of other easily reachable planets before, and if it were one of only a couple of planets currently in the right direction, finding the elevator would have been child's play, which it clearly wasn't.
3. Known that even in the area with the highest stellar density, distance between stars is still unimaginable and that there is orders of magnitude more interstellar space than stellar space.

Given these circumstances, an unguided projectile would take a really long time to reach anther star system. Even if it had gotten far enough to reach another star system, the odds of missing the system are far higher than the odds of entering it.

Is there an explanation for how this elevator ended up on an inhabited planet?